# Cross tab query is not aggregating results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

I was working from the fiddle example to create a cross tab view. Essentially, I received a table with `Customers`, `Vendors` and `Product Type`. I want to generate a view where the vendors are the rows and the columns are the total sales by product type.

The structure is

```
CustomerID Vendor ProductType
--------------------------------
1            A       Type1  
2            A       Type2  
3            B       Type1  
4            A       Type2
```

The end result I want is:

```
Vendor  Type1   Type2
---------------------
 A        1        2     
 B        1        0

/* Count the number of sales by Product Type for each Vendor. */
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(ProductType) 
                from MyTable
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Vendor,' + @cols + ' 
        from MyTable
        pivot 
        (
            count (ProductType)
            for ProductType in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p 
    ORDER BY Vendor ASC'
execute(@query)
```

The end result is multiple rows for each vendor instead of a single row with the aggregated counts.

E.g.

```
Vendor  Type1   Type2
---------------------
  A       1       0
  A       0       1
  B       1       0
  A       0       1
```

Does anyone have any insight into what I may have missed with this query?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the fiddle example?  Or can you post your table structure and some sample data?

Comment: I updated the post with sample tables. Hopefully it clarifies what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use a subquery to select the columns that you need from your table.  The problem is that your data is being grouped by the `vendor` and the `customerId`.  The `customerId` is distinct for each row, changing your query to the following will give you the result:

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(ProductType) 
                from MyTable
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query 
     = 'SELECT Vendor,' + @cols + ' 
        from
        (
          select vendor, producttype
          from MyTable
        ) d
        pivot 
        (
            count (ProductType)
            for ProductType in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p 
    ORDER BY Vendor ASC'

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5503/2). This gives a result:

```
| VENDOR | TYPE1 | TYPE2 |
|      A |     1 |     2 |
|      B |     1 |     0 |
```